# Rails Serializers: Pass param to has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization

I have two models

A has_many Bs (through A_B - includes a custom attribute)

I want to serialize them using active model serializers, which is easy - but I also want to pass a parameter to the has_many associated objects ... I was searching the web but couldn't find an answer.

```
class ASerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name
  has_many :bs, serializer: CustomBSerializer

  def custom_attribute
    A.A_Bs.first.custom_attribute
  end
end

class CustomBSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :custom_attribute

  def custom_attribute
    @options[:custom_attribute]
  end
end
```

Generally, I want to include the `custom_attribute` of A_B in the output of B

Comment: Can't you just do: `B.A_B.custom_attribute` in your `CustomBSerializer`?

Comment: Please let us know how you solved this.